# Работа с потоками boost

Tags: c++, boost

Задача: параллельно читать файлы и выводить в консоль имя файла и цифру из файла.

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost\filesystem\fstream.hpp>
#include <boost\thread\thread.hpp>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

vector<int> values;
FILE* txt;
fs::path path("c:\\text");

std::vector<boost::thread> threads;

int result = 0;

void readFile(fs::directory_iterator it) {
    fs::ifstream ifs(*it);
    if (ifs.is_open()) {
        int val;
        ifs >> val;
        //values.push_back(val);
        result += val;
        cout << it->path().filename() << ": " << val << endl;
        txt = fopen(it->path().string().c_str(), "r");
        fclose(txt);
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    }
    else {
        cerr << "Ошибка!" << endl;
    }
}
int main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    cout << "Введите путь к файлам (*.txt) (например C:\\text): ";
    cin >> path;
    cout << endl;

    for (fs::directory_iterator it(path); it != fs::directory_iterator(); ++it) {
        if (it->path().extension() == ".txt") {
            threads.push_back(boost::thread(&readFile, it));
        }
    }
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
    cout << "Сумма всех чисел: " << result << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

В итоге в консоль выводится краказябра 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если каждый новый поток вызывать с задержкой, то всё нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить проблему?

Comment: А синхронизировать вывод, например, с помощью хотя бы мьютекса - не судьба?

Comment: Было бы "судьба" - вопроса бы не было.

Comment: хочется без мютексов?

Comment: Тогда синхронизируйте вывод сообщениями в отдельный поток. Так можно или тоже за рамками ограничений?

Comment: Хочется, что бы был правильный вывод. Если можно это сделать мютексами, дай ответ как.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить в глобальных переменных:

```
std::mutex cout_m;
```

А в потоке строку

```
cout << it->path().filename() << ": " << val << endl;
```

записать как

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_m);
    cout << it->path().filename() << ": " << val << endl;
}
```

Comment: Уже пробовал. https://pp.vk.me/c639917/v639917894/1328/nrypMV2a_Ss.jpg в файлах числа 1, 10, 100... Правильный результат должен быть 1111111

Comment: Ну, вы говорили только о выводе. Чтобы верно считались суммы,  строку         `result += val;` тоже нужно внести под защиту мьютекса...